# Proving $f$ is onto using compactness and completeness

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$ be two metric spaces such that $(X, d_X)$ is compact and $(Y, d_Y)$ is complete.

Let $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in C(X,Y)$ a sequence that converges to $f \in C(X,Y)$, where $f$ is an isometry (not necessarily onto).

In part one (which I was able to complete) it was asked to prove that if $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x$ then $f_n(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$.

In part two, we are asked to prove the following:

If for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the set $(f_n(X))^o$ is dense in $Y$ then $f$ is onto.

Here is my attempt, which I *think* is 'nearly there' but which I am unable to complete. Any assistance would be much appreciated + if there's a better way, I would love to know.

**My attempt:**

Let $y \in Y$. Then, since $(f_n(X))^o$ is dense in $Y$ for all $n$, we have $y \in \overline{\big(f_n(X)\big)^o}$ for all $n$.

Since the latter is closed, there is a sequence $(a_n^k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in \big(f_n(X)\big)^o$, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} d_Y(a_n^k, y)=0$.

Since $(a_n^k) \in \big(f_n(X)\big)^o$ then $a_n^k \in f_n(X)$, meaning there are $x_n^k \in X$ such that $f_n(x_n^k) = a_n^k$.

Plugging this into the aforementioned limit we obtain:
$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} d_Y(f_n(x_n^k), y)=0$.

**[**Here is where my solution gets a bit messy and potentially off course...**]**:

$(x_n^k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $X$ and $X$ is compact, therefore sequentially compact and therefore it has a subsequence $(x_n^{k_l})_{l\in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges to some $x_n^0 \in X$.

My idea from here is to show that, since there is such a subsequence for each $n$, then the resulting sequence $(x^0_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ somehow yields a converging subsequence $(b_n)$, that converges to some $b \in X$  for which:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d_Y(f_n(b_n), y)=0$.

This, combined with part one, would mean that $y=f(b)$.

How can I complete this proof? And is there something simpler?

Comment: Which definition of convergence of functions do you use? Do you assume anything about the $f_n$, or nothing at all?

Comment: @Cronus All the details on $f_n$ are supplied, there's nothing further (note part one is probably useful to the solution and contains further details). These are metric spaces so convergence is as usual.

Comment: @Cronus to clarify - "as usual" means the sup metric $d_{\infty}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideas seem on a right track to me, but perhaps not "the" right track. I think a simpler way to prove this would be as follows:

Let $y\in Y$. We need to find $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$; since $f_{n}(X)$ is dense, there is $x_{n}\in X$ such that $d_{Y}(f_{n}(x_{n}),y)<\frac{1}{n}$. Since X is compact, there is a subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ converging to some $x\in X$. By the first part, $f_{n_{k}}(x_{n_{k}})\longrightarrow f(x)$. But clearly $f_{n_{k}}(x_{n_{k}})$ converges to $y$ (since $d_{Y}(f_{n_{k}}(x_{n_{k}}),y)<\frac{1}{n_{k}}\longrightarrow0$), so $f(x)=y$, as needed.

It is possible I am missing something, since I didn't use the fact that even $f_{n}(X)^{\circ}$ is dense in $Y$.

Comment: Do you mind explaining, even briefly, your thinking process that led you onto this? I'm trying to understand how to improve my way of thinking about such questions.

Comment: Yeah sure. For what it's worth, it was exactly this: first I saw that the image of $f_n$ was dense, which confused me, because I thought it would already mean that it is everything, since $X$ is compact and continuous images of compact spaces are closed. Then I realized you are not assuming $f_n$ is continuous. But $f$ *is* continuous (even an isometry), so I thought I should probably try to deduce $f(X)$ is dense from the fact $f_n(X)$ is dense. So I thought, take some $y\in Y$. For every $\varepsilon>0$ there is some point in $f_n(X)$ which is $\varepsilon$-close to it.

Comment: Then you could take this sequence of points and get a point in $f(X)$ which is $\varepsilon$-close to it. And therefore $f(X)$ is dense. When I wrote it down it somehow came out a bit differently, since I was sort of ignoring the functions $f_n$ in my head, and just thinking of $f_n(X)$ as subsets. But a similar thing worked. I also thought I could just take $1/n$ instead of $\varepsilon$ to cut things short a bit. This is perhaps an important point: in your attempt to took two indices, an $n$ for the function $f_n$ and a $k$ for the sequence. But it's a kind of a "classic trick" that you can

Comment: just take $n$ for both, since there's not reason to separate the two things. This makes everything - at least notationally - a bit simpler. You can think of it as taking the "diagonal" of the "double sequence" $(n,k)$.

Comment: So when I started writing it down, the thought process became a little more accurate. Take $y\in Y$, and then instead of taking $\varepsilon$, immediately look for something $1/n$-close to it in $f_n(X)$, i.e. some $x_n$ such that $f_n(x_n)$ is $1/n$-close to it. Then taking a subsequence which converges you get some $x$ which works.

Comment: I'd be happy to explain more things if you'd like, I wrote down everything that came to my mind.

Comment: This is great -- made my day :) Thank you!

Comment: @Anon sure thing :) have a good one!